# Having Issue on Uploading File(Image) To Server Through jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can you please take a look at this snippets and let me know what I am doing wrong to upload image to the `img` folder in the root directory?

I have simple inputs template like

```
Bug Title:<br>
<input type="text" name="bugTitle">
Bug Description: 
<textarea name="bugDescriotion"></textarea>
Bug Image:<br>
<input type="file" id="input" name="bug-img">
```

and a jquery Ajax request like

```
 $("#submit-bug").on("click", function(e) {
     var mdata = new FormData();
     mdata.append('bug_title', $('input[name=bugTitle]').val());
     mdata.append('bug_description', $('input[name=bugDescriotion]').val());
     mdata.append('bug_img', $('input[name=bug-img]')[0].files[0]);

     e.preventDefault();
     var request = $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "loadBugs.php",
         data: mdata,
         cache: false,

         processData: false,
         beforeSend: function() {
             console.log(mdata);
         }
     });

     request.done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
     });

     request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
         console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
     });

 });
```

and eventually a php filr called **loadBugs.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$validextensions = array("jpeg","jpg", "png");
$temporary       = explode(".", $_FILES["bug_img"]["name"]);
$file_extension  = end($temporary);
if ((($_FILES["bug_img"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
    && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
    } else {
        if (file_exists("img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";
        } else {
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
            $targetPath = "img/" . $_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
            move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath); // Moving Uploaded file
            echo "<span id='success'>Image Uploaded Successfully...!!</span><br/>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<span id='invalid'>Invalid file Size or Type<span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Did you try to debug this code?

Comment: I would recommend taking AJAX out of the picture and insure your html form and php script are working correctly.  Once you can get a file into the folder using just html and php, then add in the AJAX.

A parse error is typically a syntax error somewhere in your code.

Comment: if it's on the screen it should be a php error.  AJAX doesn't output errors to the screen in general.

Comment: try adding also `contentType: false,` to your ajax.

Comment: Thanks Ozan , I add the `contentType: false,` but no success! in the console I am getting a html format of error page

Comment: still getting `<span id='invalid'>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>` in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php   $validextensions = array("jpeg","jpg", "png");
    $type = ["image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg"];
    $file_extension  = pathinfo($_FILES["bug_img"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!in_array($_FILES["bug_img"]["type"],$type)){
            die("Wrong File type");
        }
        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) {
            die("Size not Allowed");}
        if(!in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            die("FILE EXTENSION NOT ALLOWED");
        }
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                die( "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>");
        }
        if (file_exists("img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            die($_FILES["file"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ");
        }
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
            $targetPath = "img/" . $_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)){
            echo "<span id='success'>Image Uploaded Successfully...!!</span><br/>";
        }
                    ?>
```

First of all your content type

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

is wrong, you are not returning json.

Second of all, you should check dev Tools to see what you are sending and receiving. (I didn't try it, but it should work)
Third, File EXTENSION should be checked with [PathINFO](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead of explode.

Comment: Thanks Elias I but  need to use the `header('Content-type: application/json');` since I am going to retrieve some data from database in the rest of the snippet and display them on page

Comment: Then all those html "error" you should change it to json with `json_encode()`